# Add ads on cordova apps with Admob

Tags: cordova, plugins, admob, ads

I'm searching a way to add ad with admob on my cordova app. I tried to use cordova plugin admob free ( https://github.com/ratson/cordova-plugin-admob-free ). Test ads works, but I have no results un dev mode.

Can you help me pls!

Answer (score 0):

Try admod-plus, it have more user-base and updates,
Link - https://admob-plus.github.io/